# Share Google Drive files via Facebook

Tags: google-drive, file-sharing

I just finished my enquiry to college in Google Drive and now I can't send it via Facebook.

I click "share" and then "Facebook" and it opens a window in it. I select my friends from Facebook and that gives me the answer "The message could not be posted to this Wall." Even when I try to send it in a private message this happens.

Can anybody help me figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

For Google drive files (docs, sheets, slides etc.) you can select file>Published to the web...
This will create a **PUBLIC** dynamically linked url that can be directly shared on facebook etc. or embedded.
Note as this is dynamic if you change the file these changes will also be posted to the internet.

For other files in Google drive you need to go to the advanced button on the bottom right of the share screen (accessed from the little man's head with a plus beside it that appears when you select the file). From here you can choose the access link beside the owners name and make public with link.

For both cases there is a risk that others may view the file.

Answer (score 1):

Most users will need a Google account (not Gmail), to access drive files.

The files must be shared explicitly with them, or shared public. Then the file’s (or folder’s) URL can be posted to a message in Facebook. I've run into problems when users didn't have Google accounts. I've never tried sharing directly to Facebook, just posted a properly shared Drive folder/file.

Comment: A "Gmail account" is a Google account. Why do you mean by "not Gmail"?

Answer (score 1):

After days of tinkering, I found out the details of the issue and solutions to it.
Issue: You open a shared link from google drive that was sent to you in a facebook messenger chat group or the like.

Opening the shared link on facebook will allow you to view the shared contents of the owner, but once you try to download it, you are redirected to a broken link stating Error: "access denied or you don't have authorization".

It turns out the issue is not on the owner of the drive but with how facebook treats external links. Since you opened the link on Facebook, it's the facebook browser that is granted access to the shared link, however, once you press download on any file, the Facebook browser will prompt you to a pop-up window letting you choose between browsers available in your mobile devices. And since the facebook browser redirected you to another browser(which did not have prior access to the shared link) your access will be denied and you will have no authorization.

In short, the main issue is that Facebook redirects downloads from within links viewed by the facebook browser to another browser.

Solution: Simply copy the shared link address, and manually paste it to your external browser on your phone or pc. This way, your browser(not the fb browser) is given permissions to the shared link, and on any subsequent download links you access from there onwards.

Answer (score -3):

You can share via a Facebook message only if the person is your Friend.

Comment: I tried to edit this down to what you were trying to say.  If this is true, do you have a reference for that information?